# Magento : Change product Listing Template

Tags: magento

Can you Please tell me I want to use my custom module template for product listing page when Category level is two

Answer (score 0):

Like everything in Magento you have more than one option. Choose that make more sense in your project.

1. Change te template of second levels category in admin or add custom xml in that categories.
2. Attach an event on  that checks the current category level and add a new handle when the category is second.
   After that you can use layout xml to change the template.
   To add a new handle you should use:

`

```
$_category = Mage::registry('current_category');
if ($_category instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Category && $_category->getLevel() == 2){
    $update = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getUpdate();
    $update->addHandle('CATEGORY_LEVEL_2');
}
```

Ref: http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/creating-custom-layout-handles/

3. Like second option you can also attach an observer to block and change the template directly on it. For this the event is  and the observer code is like:

`

```
if ($observer->getBlock() instanceof Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_View) {
     $observer->getBlock()->setTemplate('my_module/newtemplate.phtml');
}
```

Ref: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/22218/remove-price-block-via-event-observer